# ASP.NET Charting - Y value doesn't start at 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, datatable

I'm working on a chart in asp.net that is dinamically created from a DataTable. Basically I've got a DataTable like this:

[image]

So, what I want in my chart is a column for each differente location, and for each diferent Type I want to have a "portion" of the column, meaning I would like to have a column per location divided per type.

I have managed to do something like this, but not quite what I would like:

[image]

Now I'll try to explain my code.

First, i add the different locations in my datatable to a list of strings

```
string loc = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dtTipos.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (loc != dtTipos.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString())
        listaLocais.Add(dtTipos.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString());

    loc = dtTipos.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString();
}
```

After, for each different location, I select the rows to the corresponding location and create a series for each one of them. I proceed to create a point with y=0 and one with y=total

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaLocais.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow[] lRow = dtTipos.Select("Location = '" + listaLocais[i] + "'");
    foreach (DataRow dr in lRow)
    {
        string serie = dr["Location"].ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "_" + dr["Type"].ToString() + " - " + dr["Total"].ToString();
        Series s = new Series();
        s.Name = serie;
        s.Label = dr["Location"].ToString();
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        chartTipo1.Series.Add(s);

        s.Points.AddXY(i + 1, 0);
        s.Points[0].Label = " ";
        s.Points.AddXY(i + 1,Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total"].ToString()));
        s.Points[1].Label = " ";// dtTipos.Rows[i]["Total"].ToString();
    }
}
```

The thing is: I think that because I create a serie for each row, everytime I use a diferent column, the y axis starts from where I left it.

Is there any way so I can get this to work?
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your series and data points in the same loop. First add your series, then your data points:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new MyDataTable();

        //first add your series
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] { "Type" }).Rows)
        {
            Series series = new Series();
            series.Name = (string)row["Type"];
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
            Chart1.Series.Add(series);
        }

        // then add your points;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            Chart1.Series[(string)row["Type"]].Points.AddXY(row["Location"], new object[] { row["Total"] });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple. However, got a different problem now. Not all the locations are appearing in the chart (I have 6 locations but only 4 appear). Is this caused by having some types repeated in the missing locations?

Comment: In order to give you a definitive answer, you would have to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can reproduce your specific problem. If my post solved your current problem please remember to mark it as accepted and then post a new question with your new problem, but make sure you know how to ask a proper question as described in the link above.

Comment: I'm having trouble putting the information in the right column, it keeps getting mixed up - the wrong values are going to the wrong locations.

Should I make another question for this or edit this one?

Comment: Please post a new question with enough specific details so people can help.

Comment: Will do so. Thank you for your help.